# VS2010, с++. Подсветка синтаксиса

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resharper

1) Как сделать расширенную цветную подсветку синтаксиса кода в VS2010 для C++? Может, расширение какое-нибудь. Например, как в ReSharper C++ (имена методов один цвет, имена классов - другой, и т.п.). В VS2010 для этого случая есть только цвет для "Идентификатора", но он общий для всех классов, методов и т.п. 2) Как в ReSharper C++ отключить всё (проверки, расширения функционала и т.п.), оставив только расширенную подсветку синтаксиса? Спасибо

Comment: Может вам стоит перейти на актуальную версию VS, где это все есть из коробки?

Comment: @VTT Я буду разрабатывать под автокад 2013, который требует vs2010. Ни больше, ни меньше.

Comment: Тогда может вам стоит перейти на актуальную версию VS, где это все из коробки, и [использовать тулсет от VS2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/)?

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл накатить решапер? На 2010? Или привыкать без рюшечек.. 2017 по быстродействию сильно отстаёт от 2010 кстати, так что возможно и имеет смысл. И где то был приличный плагин на тему раскраски, гляну в архиве название если не забуду..

Comment: думаю, нужен этот https://www.wholetomato.com/ - он даже для 6 студии неплохо раскрашивал и делал много других чудес, когда решарперов ещё не было

Comment: @VTT, с тулсетом немного попробовал, вроде все работает, спасибо. Только я не понял, как пометить сообщение как ответ

Comment: @KoVadim, буду ознакамливатся с данной надстройкой. Вроде то, что нужно! )